# How can I present the day and time in a more presentable way from sql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am presenting information from the database using php but I want to present it in a more friendly way instead of 2015-05-09 20:15:00.

what can I do to change it in a friendly way.

Many thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tables.css">
<?php 
require './db/connect.php'; 
include './includes/header.php';
?>

<h2>Performances</h2>
<div class="performtable">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th><u>Performance Name:</u></th>
        <th><u>Performance Date and Time:</u></th>
</tr><br>
<?php 
    if($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM performance")){
        if($count = $result->num_rows){
            while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
            ?>
<tr>
    <td class="firstcolumn">
        <?php echo $row->Name; ?>
    </td>
    <td class="secondcolumn">
        <?php echo $row->Time;
        }?>
    </td>
    <td class="">

    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>


                <?php
      $result->free();  
    }
}
mysqli_close($connection);

include './includes/footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Define: **a friendly way**...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Comment: what is a friendly way?

Comment: @Naruto I mean in a way like saturday 5th may 2015 8.00pm

Comment: @bub see comment above

Comment: @Naruto it is as Timestamp at the moment

Comment: The answer of carlos explains it all.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strtotime()

```
$datetime = '2015-05-09 20:15:00';
echo date('l dS \o\f F Y h:i:s A', strtotime($datetime));
```

Or using another patterns like

```
date('H:i d/m/Y', strtotime($datetime));
```

Or

```
date('d/m H:i', strtotime($datetime));
```

Look what can you do in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT START...**

To use what I showed just change:

```
<?php echo $row->Time;
```

with,

```
<?php echo date_create($row->Time, 'l, j F H:i:s');
```

**EDIT END...**

It depends on yor definition of "friendly". For example this:

```
$date = date_create('2015-05-09 20:15:00');
echo date_format($date, 'l, j F H:i:s');
```

Would output:

```
Saturday, 9 May 20:15:00
```

There are a lot of variables that you can use! Take a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Comment: Yes this is what I want how can I incorporate this into my query to display like this currently I am selecting all from the table and echoing it out.

Comment: For responding that accurately we need your PHP code where you are quering your database, maybe you can edit your question so we can post a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are already some good answers for how to format the date using PHP, but if you want to do the formatting in your MySQL query you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Like the PHP date formatting, there are many formatting options available (although I believe PHP is more robust).

So for example for a data like Jan 12, 2015 9:00pm:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%b %d, %Y %r') as formatted_date;
```

You can replace `NOW()` with any datetime or datetime column. You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to convert a timestamp to a datetime.

Useful stuff: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = date("d/m/Y"); 
$time = date("H:i:s");
```

Now you can "play" with variables like you want.